# Double sum factorial manipulation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, factorial

$$\sum_{B = 0}^{n-1} \sum_{A = 0}^{n-B-1} \frac{(n-1)!}{B!(n-B-1)!} \frac{(n-B-1)!}{A!(n-B-A-1)!} \frac{A}{A+B+1}$$

This is driving me nuts! Is there anyway to reduce

$$\sum_{B = 0}^{n-1} \sum_{A = 0}^{n-B-1} \frac{(n-1)!}{A!B!(n-A-B-1)!} \frac{A}{A+B+1}$$

beyond

$$\sum_{B = 0}^{n-1} \sum_{A = 0}^{n-B-1} \frac{(n-1)!}{(A-1)!B!(n-A-B-1)!} \frac{1}{A+B+1}$$

I can't figure out how to deal with that $\frac{1}{A+B+1}$ term in any way that brings it inside the $\frac{1}{n-A-B-1}$ term. Is this not possible?

Comment: My first instinct is to rewrite this with binomial coefficients or multinomial coefficients as that may help direct me to certain patterns.  $\sum\limits_{B=0}^{n-1}\sum\limits_{A=0}^{n-B-1} \binom{n-1}{B}\binom{n-1-B}{A}\frac{A}{A+B+1}$.  So, it looks like we might be in a scenario where there are $n$ total people, one of which is special.  We choose $B$ of the non-special people to be in one group and we choose $A$ of the remaining non-special people to be in another group.  Further, we range over all possible values of $A,B$.  If it weren't for that $\frac{A}{A+B+1}$ it would be $3^{n-1}$

Comment: Exactly - this problem actually originates with a multinomial distribution that I'm multiplying by that $\frac{A}{A+B+1}$ term. The denominator $A+B+1$ is killing me though. I can't get it inside the factorial no matter how I try. The binomial case ($A+1$ or $B + 1$ is easy to handle.

Comment: Plugging it into Wolframalpha gives a solution in the form of a DifferenceRoot, oddly enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{B=0}^{n-1}}&\color{blue}{\sum_{A=0}^{n-B-1}\binom{n-1}{B}\binom{n-1-B}{A}\frac{A}{A+B+1}}\\
> &=\sum_{B=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{B}\sum_{A=1}^{n-1-B}\binom{n-1-B}{A}A\int_{0}^{1}z^{A+B}\,dz\tag{1}\\
> &=\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{B=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{B}\sum_{A=1}^{n-1-B}\binom{n-2-B}{A-1}(n-1-B)z^{A+B}\,dz\tag{2}\\
> &=\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{B=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{B}(n-1-B)\sum_{A=0}^{n-2-B}\binom{n-2-B}{A}z^{A+B+1}\,dz\tag{3}\\
> &=\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{B=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{B}(n-1-B)z^{B+1}(1+z)^{n-2-B}\,dz\tag{4}\\  
> &=\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{B=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-2}{B}(n-1)z^{B+1}(1+z)^{n-2-B}\,dz\tag{5}\\    
> &=(n-1)\int_{0}^{1}z\sum_{B=0}^{n-2}\binom{n-2}{B}z^B(1+z)^{n-2-B}\,dz\\      
> &=(n-1)\int_{0}^{1}z(1+2z)^{n-2}\,dz\tag{6}\\      
> &=\frac{n-1}{4}\int_{1}^{3}(u-1)u^{n-2}\,du\tag{7}\\      
> &=\frac{n-1}{4}\int_{1}^{3}\left(u^{n-1}-u^{n-2}\right)\,du\\      
> &=\frac{n-1}{4}\left.\left(\frac{1}{n}u^n-\frac{1}{n-1}u^{n-1}\right)\right|_{1}^{3}\\
> &=\frac{n-1}{4}\left(\frac{3^n-1}{n}-\frac{3^{n-1}-1}{n-1}\right)\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{3^{n-1}}{2}-\frac{3^n-1}{4n}}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the integral to get rid of the denominator. We also start the inner sum with $A=1$.
- In (2) we use the binomial identity $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p-1}{q-1}\frac{p}{q}$.
- In (3) we shift the index of the inner sum to start with $A=0$.
- In (4) we apply the binomial theorem.
- In (5) we use the binomial identity $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p-1}{p-q-1}\frac{p}{p-q}$.
- In (6) we use again the binomial theorem.
- In (7) we substitute $1+2z=u, 2dz=du$.

Comment: Just checking, where do you get the $1+2z$ in going from (3) to (4)? Shouldn't it be $1+z$?

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Yes, thanks for pointing at the mistake.

Comment: In the second line of (5) there seems to be a spurious $(n-1).$

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Thanks again, Marko.

Comment: Can you check (3) to (4)? (Duplicate $n-1-B.$)

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Corrected and more thoroughly reviewed. Many thanks for your patience and watchfulness.

Comment: Verified it one more time. (+1).

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Many thanks, Marko.

Comment: Wow, that's beautiful. Thank you, @MarkusScheuer. I can used this in a lot of places.

Comment: @dreicht: You're welcome.

Comment: Does this process become impossible if multiply the original equation by $p^q^B(1-p-q)^(n-1-A-B)$? IE $\sum_{B = 0}^{n-1} \sum_{A = 0}^{n-1-B} {n-1 \choose B} {n - 1 - B \choose A} \frac{A}{A+B+1}p^A q^B (1-p-q)^{n-1-A-B}$

Answer (score 0):

Wolfram Alpha found this sequence which seems to match the sum for all positive integers...

$$ a_n = \frac{3^{n-1}}{2} - \frac{3^n - 1}{4n} $$

Comment: Can I ask how you got this? What did you enter into Wolfram? I'm entering the sums and I don't get this, but it evaluates to the same answer.

Comment: @dreicht By calculating the first few values of the sum with $n=1,2,3\dots$, and tried to get Wolfram to identify the sequence... it didn't work, so I tried removing the fractions by multiplying everything by $n$, which did [work](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0%2C1%2C7%2C34%2C142%2C547%2C2005%2C7108)

Comment: Thank you! Didn't think of trying that.